# How to access to users files of windows 10 from HDD?

Tags: linux, windows-10, data-recovery, linux-mint, hard-drive-recovery

I have the next problem, the HDD of my sister's computer cannot start windows 10. So she wants to get the files of her user. I bought a HDD reader to get the files. When I try to access to her user folder to get the files, I can only see administrator and default users but her user folder doesn't appear.

Do you have any idea how I can do that?

I tried with an old HDD of another computer (windows 7) and it works but windows 10 no idea.

I don't have a problem if the solution is in Linux or Windows I use these systems.

[image: Folder of users, it shows administrator, default, and public access]

Comment: What "reader" did you buy and how are you using it? How are you physically connecting to the drive to try to read it?

Comment: Are you sure the files _are_ still there? Ask your sister whether she tried to do a "Reset" or a reinstall before?

Comment: @music2myear I bought a reader of HDD [link](https://www.amazon.com.mx/TECHVIDA-Transparente-Compatible-Extra%C3%ADble-computadora/dp/B092VBBPXF/ref=sr_1_4?adgrpid=56254826565&gclid=CjwKCAiA76-dBhByEiwAA0_s9QL2lsiqCVrQc2oFY2PGfw-Z1xXriY7YGyu4kSliF3VkG-dTXVjkXBoCUHEQAvD_BwE&hvadid=590550283809&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=1010150&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=b&hvrand=8826599809920844951&hvtargid=kwd-337316870578&hydadcr=26980_14537417&keywords=dock+hdd+ide+sata&qid=1672245347&sr=8-4) and I'm connneting with usb port to my PC

Comment: @user1686 I asked to her, and she said "Windows tried an autofix and says that it have a problem with a start file"

Comment: @user1686 I tried to fix the start file by reading the official docs of Microsoft but doesn't work

Comment: The OS was reinstalled already, deleting and overwriting the previous user folders. If you're lucky, SOME content may be able to be recovered. You should take the HDD to a competent local PC tech if these files are valuable.